# How to find X-RateLimit-Limit of a particular website

Tags: http-headers, rate-limiting

This question may be silly but I want to know is there any way to read the X-RateLimit-Limit of a website if it exists?

And if so, how to read it? I have a website which blocks me after many requests and later restores after sometime...